# How does Symfony generate the id/name for a form field?

Tags: symfony

In `buildForm()` I would like to extract the full id/name of the current form field node.  `$builder->getName()` returns only the name of the current node but I need the full property path, for example:

```
id="type_employments_0_location"
name="type[employments][0][location]"
```

Is there any way to generate this while *building* the form?

I'm working on a custom mandatory field type extension that looks up the "mandatoriness" of each field as the form is built; hence I need the full property path in `buildForm()` so that I can modify the options array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a nutshell:  The full property path generated by the form framework is not available to `buildForm()` but is available to `buildView()` and `finishView()`.  Use those if you need access to the full property path.

Answer (score 1):

From the [FormConfigInterface](http://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/Form/FormConfigInterface.html), You should be able to use `$builder->getPropertyPath()`.

It will return a PropertyPathInterface object, just use it as a string to get the real property path as string (i.e. `print $builder->getPropertyPath()` will give `type[employments][0][location]`).

Comment: Does this work in `buildForm()`?  Calling `$builder->getPropertyPath()` in `buildForm()` seems to just return null.  Calling `$form->getPropertyPath()` in `buildView()` works, though that's too late in creation of the form to achieve what I want to do.

Comment: I tried it from inside the `buildForm` method of a FormType and it works well by my side.

Comment: Hmm.. What version of Symfony are you using?  I'm in 2.8.

Comment: Same version! :) http://prnt.sc/b5iyr1 . Note that this is the buildForm method of a child Type (here LinkType) embedded as field in the parent form (PageType), and the `property_path` option of the (LinkType) field is (hard) set.

Comment: I see now.  Apparently if `'property_path'` is manually defined we can retrieve it from within `buildForm()`, however the property path generated by Symfony is not available until after the entire form is build and (I guess) the view has been created.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it's pretty easy.
For every field type has many variables assigned.

```
<label for="{{ form.fieldname.vars.id }}">...</label>
```

From symfony doc ([Form Variables Reference](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html#form-variables-reference)):

> variables are common to every field type. Certain field types may have
> even more variables and some variables here only really apply to
> certain types.
>
> Assuming you have a form variable in your template and you want to
> reference the variables on the name field, accessing the variables is
> done by using a public vars property on the FormView object.

[Form Variables Reference](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html#form-variables-reference)

Comment: I need this in `builldForm()` before the view is created so that I can add values to the options array.  I will clarify in the question.